# Error al imprimir el numero index de un elemento de una lista: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, diccionarios

Estoy haciendo una pokedex de kanto con diccionarios en Python,pero lo único que sale en mi código es dicho error, además de que solo quiero que me imprima el index y no el elemento que tiene el index....

Aquí anexo mi código:

```
print("Bienvenido a la Pokedex ")
Pokemon=(input("Introduce a un Pokemon:"))

Pokedex_de_Kanto={"Missigno":0,"Bulbasaur":1,"Ivysaur":2,"Venusaur":3,"Charmander":4,"Charmeleon":5,"Charizard":6,"Squirtle":7,"Wartortle":8,"Blastoise":9,"Caterpie":10,"Metapod":11,"Butterfree":12,"Weedle":13,"Kakuna":14,"Beedrill":15,"Pidgey":16,"Pidgeotto":17,"Pidgeot":18,"Rattata":19,"Raticate":20,"Spearow":21,"Fearow":22,"Ekans":23,"Arbok":24,"Pikachu":25,"Raichu":26,"Sandshrew":27,"Sandslash":28,"Nidoran♀":29,"Nidorina":30,"Nidoqueen":31,"Nidoran♂":32,"Nidorino":33,"Nidoking":34,"Clefairy":35,"Clefable":36,"Vulpix":37,"Ninetales":38,"Jigglypuff":39,"Wigglytuff":40,"Zubat":41,"Golbat":42,"Oddish":43,"Gloom":44,"Vileplume":45,"Paras":46,"Parasect":47,"Venonat":48,"Venomoth":49,"Diglett":50,"Dugtrio":51,"Meowth ":52,"Persian":53,"Psyduck":54,"Golduck":55,"Mankey":56,"Primeape":57,"Growlithe":58,"Arcanine":59,"Poliwag":60,"Poliwhirl":61,"Poliwrath":62,"Abra":63,"Kadabra":64,"Alakazam":65,"Machop":66,"Machoke":67,"Machamp":68,"Bellsprout":69,"Wepinbell":70,"Victreebel":71,"Tentacool":72,"Tentacruel":73,"Geodude":74,"Graveler":75,"Golem":76,"Ponyta":77,"Rapidash":78,"Slowpoke":79,"Slowbro":80,"Magnemite":81,"Magneton":82,"Farfetch'd":83,"Doduo":84,"Dodrio":85,"Seel":86,"Dewgong":87,"Grimer":88,"Muk":89,"Shellder":90,"Cloyster":91,"Gastly":92,"Haunter":93,"Gengar":94,"Onix":95,"Drowzee":96,"Hypno":97,"Krabby":98,"Kingler":99,"Voltorb":100,"Electrode":101,"Exeggcute":102,"Exeggutor":103,"Cubone":104,"Marowak":105,"Hitmonlee":106,"Hitmonchan":107,"Lickitung":108,"Koffing":109,"Weezing":110,"Rhyhorn":111,"Rhydon":112,"Chansey":113,"Tangela":114,"Kangaskhan":115,"Horsea":116,"Seadra":117,"Goldeen":118,"Seaking":119,"Staryu":120,"Starmie":121,"Mr. Mime":122,"Scyther":123,"Jynx":124,"Electabuzz":125,"Magmar":126,"Pinsir":127,"Tauros":128,"Magikarp":129,"Gyarados":130,"Lapras":131,"Ditto":132,"Eevee":133,"Vaporeon":134,"Jolteon":135,"Flareon":136,"Porygon":137,"Omanyte":138,"Omastar":139,"Kabuto":140,"Kabutops":141,"Aerodactyl":142,"Snorlax":143,"Articuno":144,"Zapdos":145,"Moltres":146,"Dratini":147,"Dragonair":148,"Dragonite":149,"Mewtwo":150,"Mew":151}
print ()
if Pokemon in Pokedex_de_Kanto:
    print (Pokedex_de_Kanto.index(Pokemon))
else:
    print("Pokemon no disponible")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los errores en Python suelen ser muy descriptivos, en inglés, pero descriptivos:

> ErrorDeAtributo: el objeto 'dict' no tiene el atributo 'index'

De eso sacamos dos conclusiones:

- `Pokedex_de_Kanto` es un diccionario (`dict`).
- Los objetos de tipo `dict` no tiene ningún método o atributo llamado `index`.

Y es que los diccionarios no tienen el método `index`, ese método es de las listas (`list`) y tuplas (`tuple`) que son contenedores ordenados e indizables:

```
lista = ["Missigno", "Bulbasaur", "Ivysaur", "Venusaur"]
pokemon = "Ivysaur"
try:
    print(lista.index(pokemon))
except ValueError:
    print("Pokemon no disponible")
```

---

A un diccionario se accede mediante sus claves (en tu caso los nombres de los pokemons). Si con `índex` te refieres al valor asociado a cada clave (el entero), entonces debes hacer algo como:

```
if Pokemon in Pokedex_de_Kanto:
    print(Pokedex_de_Kanto[Pokemon])
else:
    print("Pokemon no disponible")
```

o mejor, solo una búsqueda en el diccionario:

```
try:
    print(Pokedex_de_Kanto[Pokemon])
except KeyError:
    print("Pokemon no disponible")
```

o aún mejor, `usa dict.get()`:

```
if index:= Pokedex_de_Kanto.get(Pokemon):
    print(index)
else:
    print("Pokemon no disponible")
```

Si de verdad quisieras la posición de una clave en el diccionario, lo cual solo tiene sentido en Python >= 3.7 ya que antes los diccionarios no mantenían el orden de inserción, puedes hacer algo como:

```
for index, key in enumerate(Pokedex_de_Kanto):
    if key == Pokemon:
        print(index)
        break
else:
    print("Pokemon no disponible")
```

Aunque de poco te sirve porque no puedes indizar con un entero sobre un diccionario...

Comment: Que genial,muchas gracias colega,realmente me ayudo,el codigo que dejaste al final ayudo en poder imprimir la posicion.Muchas Gracias :)